# python - How to get list of instances of inner/nested class created only at one outer instance

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I have following code that defines outer and inner classes. I would like to get the instances of the inner class created under one specific instance of the outer class.

```
class schema():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    class node():
        nodes=[]
        def __init__(self,name):
            self.name=name
            self.nodes.append(self)
        def __call__(self):
            return(self.name)
```

When I create two instances of the class `schema` with two different instances of the inner class `node` **I would like to get only the instances of the inner class associated to one of the outer instance**.

```
a=schema('A')
a1=a.node('A1')
a2=a.node('A2')

b=schema('B')
b1=b.node('B1')
b2=b.node('B2')

print({n() for n in a.node.nodes})
```

I get:

```
{'B1', 'A1', 'B2', 'A2'}
```

But I would like to get:

```
{'A1', 'A2'}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Inner classes don't store a reference to their outer class (or vice versa). Better you rename the inner class (e. g. "_node"), and add a method "node" to outer class which creates a node object and records the connection between objects somewhere.

Comment: The issue is with `nodes=[]`. It needs to be under `__init__(self,name):` to do what you want but that causes other errors.  Still researching.